# How to list partition in a dialog menu?

Tags: partitioning, bash, dialog

Is there any way to allow the user to select a partition from *dialog*’s menu (`--menu`) selection feature? If so, how do you do it?

Of course, this does not work:

```
dialog --menu "Select a partition" 0 0 0 $(fdisk -l)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you currently already have and how it does not work. As the question is currently posed, the answer could be simply "yes".

Comment: @pLumo now done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `dialog` should be fine, so the question is "**How to print partititions?**"

Instead of `fdisk`, I'd use `lsblk`, which has cleaner output and can be run by unprivileged user.

But `lsblk` is still printing too much, we can limit it using `--output` to include only the information we're interested. Add `-n` to omit printing header.

```
lsblk -n --output TYPE,KNAME
```

Then use `awk` to filter only devices where `TYPE` is `part` and print a counter instead:

```
lsblk -n --output TYPE,KNAME | awk '$1=="part"{print i++,$2}'
```

So in total, something like this should work:

```
dialog --menu "Select partition :" 20 40 4 \
  $(lsblk -n --output TYPE,KNAME | awk '$1=="part"{print i++,$2}')
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could do *print ++i,$2*